# Apache 2.2 rewrite with proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, vhosts

Using Apache 2.2 on an older Ubuntu (12.04)...

Would like to have a path that proxies to another domain (but leaving the URL in the browser unchanged).  Tried the following since Proxy stuff isn't allowed in `htaccess` (assuming not for Apache 2.2 but maybe later versions):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  SSLProxyEngine on

  <Proxy *>
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /axis <some domain>
  ProxyPassReverse /axis <some domain>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works but not when target domain redirects.  For example, if the **some domain** redirects to `/somepath` then instead of pointing to `http://<my domain>/axis/somepath` the result is `http:://<my domain>/somepath` which isn't defined.

Question is how to force everything under a path on my domain (e.g. `/axis`) to match up with another domain?

Answer (score 0):

An app should either know about the URL structure used to access it, be very good at deducing it, or use well-crafted relative URLs (not root-relative) so that it essentially doesn't matter. The issue is that the content must contain the public URLs, otherwise you have to post-process everything, which is difficult and error-prone.

Try moving the `<some domain>` site's content from the root directory to an `axis` sub-directory. You may have to change some things but at least the URL structures will be identical.

If the system is not designed to be run from a sub-directory, you'll have no (reliable) choice other than fix the URLs it creates.